# FFmpeg. avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264) return false

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, кодировка

**Суть проблемы:** Не могу подключить кодек h264 для кодирования и декодирования кадров.

---

**Описание:**

Я скачал библиотеку ffmpeg отсюда https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/, версию dev.

Подключил её к проекту QT:

```
extern "C" 
{    
     #include <libavcodec\avcodec.h>
     #include <libavformat\avformat.h>
     #include <libavformat\avio.h>
     #include <libswscale\swscale.h>
     #include <libavutil\mem.h>
}

#pragma comment(lib,"avcodec.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"avformat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"swscale.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"avutil.lib")
```

Далее вызываю функцию: `avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264)`, возвращает false.

В ReadMe файле библиотеки сказано, что она собрана с ключами компиляции --enable-libx264 и --enable-gpl в том числе, то есть кодек h264 должен быть.

Если вызываю: `avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO)`, то возвращает объект AVCodec, как и должна.

Использую компилятор MinGW. Операционная система Windows 7.

Как можно решить или обойти проблему? Скомпилировать библиотеку самому пока не получается. Подключать исходники и "ковыряться" в них я так понял, что тоже бессмысленно.

---

**Ещё раз опишу свою проблему:**

Мне необходимо кодировать кодеком h264(можно VP9) отдельные кадры в одной программе, и потом их декодировать в другой программе. Можно использовать другие библиотеки. Язык программирования C++. Необходимо, чтобы кодек использовал межкадровое сжатие, а не просто отдельно жал кадры.

Идеи. Советы. Предложения.

Comment: Если используете MinGW . Вы подключили библиотеку [x264](http://videolan.org/developers/x264.html) ?

Comment: Если ffmpeg была собрана с ключом --enable-libx26, то строка "av_register_all();" должна добавить все кодеки из библиотеки. Если вы о таком подключении, то да.

Comment: Я не о программе ffmpeg , Я о вашей программе . Вы в свою программу подключили библиотеку x264 ?

Comment: Нет, подскажите, как это сделать? Нужно ли её отдельно скачивать?

Comment: Где работаете в отдельном MinGW или в MSYS2 ?

Comment: Я работаю в Qt, который настроен на скаченный вместе с ним MinGW

Comment: Добавьте библиотеку   [x264](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html) в свой проект. Как добавили библиотеку `avcodec` , `avformat` и другие.

Answer (score 2):

> Идеи. Советы. Предложения

Я использую систему [MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io/) там установлен ffmpeg-2.8

```
 AVCodec * codec;
 av_register_all();
 codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
 if(codec != NULL){
   printf(" codec : %s\n",codec->name);
 }
 else{
   printf(" codec : NULL\n");
 }
```

вывод

> codec : libx264

MSYS2  это набор unix утилит собраных для windows . Устанавливаете MSYS2 сразу настраиваются переменые среды , запускаете оболочку MSYS2 там запускается bash и в нем можно работат. И используя утилиту `pacman` нужно установить `mingw` `ffmpeg` `qt`

Comment: Я немного не понял, как вы используете MYSY2 и ffmpeg-2.8 в нем.
Моё предположение: Устанавливаем MSYS2, как я понял - это командная строка для добавления Unix пакетов и библиотек в MinGW.
Далее добавляем через MSYS2 ffmpeg-2.8 в MinGW или он уже это как-то сделал..
Далее пишем c++ код приведенный вами в своей IDE, выбираем компилятор MinGW.
Ещё наверно нужно подключить ffmpeg как-то и откуда-то, как?
Дальше запускаем и всё работает..